# Unable to import tailwind CSS into cypress component tests in an angular application

Tags: angular, cypress, tailwind-css, cypress-component-test-runner, cypress-component-testing

I am new to Cypress component testing and struggling to load the third-party CSS library like Tailwind CSS into my component script file. I have followed this tutorial to the tee

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vJ0rDP4CG-w

but for some reason, the tailwind CSS is not loaded. I am facing this issue

[image]

My log is giving me  this error

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/tailwindcss/tailwind.css 1:0
```

Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

> @tailwind base;
> |
> | @tailwind components;

My component.ts file looks like this

```js
// ***********************************************************
// This example support/component.ts is processed and
// loaded automatically before your test files.
//
// This is a great place to put global configuration and
// behavior that modifies Cypress.
//
// You can change the location of this file or turn off
// automatically serving support files with the
// 'supportFile' configuration option.
//
// You can read more here:
// https://on.cypress.io/configuration
// ***********************************************************

// Import commands.js using ES2015 syntax:
import './commands'

// Alternatively you can use CommonJS syntax:
// require('./commands')

import { mount } from 'cypress/angular'

import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css"
// Augment the Cypress namespace to include type definitions for
// your custom command.
// Alternatively, can be defined in cypress/support/component.d.ts
// with a <reference path="./component" /> at the top of your spec.
declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
      mount: typeof mount
    }
  }
}

Cypress.Commands.add('mount', mount)
```

Upon further research, it turns out that I might not have a scss and URL loaders so I did

> npm i --save-dev url-loader  and
> npm i --save-dev sass-loader node-sass

so my custom webpack file looks like

```js
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.(s(a|c)ss)$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg|jpg|png)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

and I am passing my custom webpack configuration into my cypress config file like that

```js
 devServer: {
      framework: "angular",
      bundler: "webpack",
      webpackConfig: require("webpack.custom.js"),
      options: {
        projectConfig: {
          root: '',
          sourceRoot: '',
          buildOptions: {
            outputPath: 'dist/frontend/browser"',
            index: 'src/index.html',
            main: 'src/main.ts',
            polyfills: 'src/polyfills.ts',
            tsConfig: 'tsconfig.app.json',
            inlineStyleLanguage: 'scss',
            assets: ["src/assets", "src/robots.txt", "src/static-404-page.html", "src/static-500-page.html"],
            styles: ["src/angular-material.scss", "src/styles.scss"],
            scripts: [],
            buildOptimizer: false,
            optimization: false,
            vendorChunk: true,
            extractLicenses: false,
            sourceMap: true,
            namedChunks: true,
          },
        },
      },
    },
```

And finally, my component-index.html file looks like this, as close as to my prod environment

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preload" href="https://example.com/fonts/icons/style.css" as="style" />
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://example.com/" />
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://example.com/" />
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://api.example.com/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.com/fonts/icons/style.css" />
    <title>Components App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div data-cy-root></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Despite all these configurations, I am still getting the same error, can someone tell me what is missing here?